# Install php 7.2 specific version 7.2.0 instead last version from apt

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, php-7.2

I need install **PHP 7.2.0**. But the problem is, when i execute apt-get install the last version **7.2.17**:

`apt install php7.2-fpm php7.2 php7.2-common php7.2-gmp php7.2-curl php7.2-soap php7.2-bcmath php7.2-intl php7.2-mbstring php7.2-xmlrpc php7.2-mysql php7.2-gd php7.2-xml php7.2-cli php7.2-zip`

Theres a easy way to install this specific version?

I'm running a vps with Ubuntu 16

Comment: This belongs elsewhere - `unix.stackexchange.com` perhaps.  Basically tho, see what versions are in your repo lists with `apt-cache madison php7.2` and then install a specific version with `apt-get install php7.2=packageversionstring`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apt-get didnt work for me. The solution was install PHP 7.2.0 from sources.

```
# curl -O -L https://github.com/php/php-src/archive/php-7.2.0.tar.gz
# tar -zxvf php-7.2.0.tar.gz 
# cd php-src-php-7.2.0/
# ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php --enable-fpm --disable-short-tags --with-openssl --with-pcre-regex --with-pcre-jit --with-zlib --enable-bcmath --with-bz2 --enable-calendar --with-curl --enable-exif 
--with-gd --enable-intl --enable-mbstring --with-mysqli --enable-pcntl --with-pdo-mysql --enable-soap --enable-sockets --with-xmlrpc --enable-zip --with-webp-dir --with-jpeg-dir --with-png-dir --with-xls --enable-fpm

# make

# make install
```